# Azure functions Service Bus output binding

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-functions

Today, I updated my VS 2017 to version 15.3 (the latest). I also installed Azure functions extension (Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions) and Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions -Version 1.0.0. 
Prior to the update, I was using the 15.3 preview and Microsoft Azure WebJobs Tools extension with Install-Package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions alpha 6. My Azure functions worked fine with Service Bus binding as output.
After the update, the output binding stopped working.
Error message:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'FunctionName'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'test' to type
>   String&. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If
>   you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make
>   sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in
>   your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(),
>   etc.).

Can anyone please provide some help on this?

Comment: Please post a code snippet that contains your function signature including all attributes

Comment: [FunctionName("CreateApp")]
        public static HttpResponseMessage CreateApp([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, 
            [ServiceBus("writequeue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")] out string test,
            TraceWriter log)

Comment: I reverted back to Install-Package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions -Version 1.0.0-alpha6 rather than using the latest version. Without changing any code, the app works again. The issue must be with the latest functions sdk.